# Who manages ISR in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I understand Kafka has the ISR mechanism to manage leader-follower data replication, but I'm just wondering who exactly updates the ISR?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each partition, the current leader tracks and manages the current in-sync replicas. Followers send Fetch requests to the leader to retrieve records. That enables the leader to keep track where each follower is and determine which ones are in-sync.

Before Kafka 2.7, each leader would update its partition state znode in ZooKeeper. Now (with [KIP-497](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-497%3A+Add+inter-broker+API+to+alter+ISR)) when the in-sync replicas change, leaders send an [AlterISR request](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_AlterIsr) to the controller and it's the controller that is responsible for updating ZooKeeper.

Comment: Thank you Mickael, that's exactly what I'm asking for.